# Firefox status bar is missing

Tags: firefox

This is quite annoying. I was not even in the edit toolbar menu, just normal browsing. I clicked on the status bar and now it is completely missing, restarted FF and still missing. Firefox version: 14.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the add-on bar (View menu / Toolbars / Add-on Bar, or just press Ctrl+/ to toggle)? Firefox hasn't has a status bar for quite some time now, so if you want it back you'll probably need to use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/ or similar.

Comment: i needed it for using https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3fox/developers thanks

Comment: Pity, I like the option to see a status bar. Thanks for confirming. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps click `Ctrl + /` by accident? That's the shortcut for opening/closing the add-on bar, which I'm assuming is what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The bar that has disappeared many people refer to as "staus bar" - the correct name is "Add-on Bar". In your top menu of Firefox go to View > Toolbars > Add-on Bar. It should have a tick next to it. Don't ask me why sometimes it seems to untick itself but that is how you get it to show again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox 3.x, and by clicking around the status bar got misplaced and maybe the other toolbars as well (e.g. the Menu bar, Navigation toolbar, Bookmark toolbar, etc.), here's a quick fix:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>
2. Click the **View** menu then **Toolbars**
3. Make the appropriate selections to activate any missing toolbars