# Is there a way to show the status bar in Fire Fox 15

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox status bar is missing](https://superuser.com/questions/460701/firefox-status-bar-is-missing)

It looks like Mozilla removed the status bar from Fire Fox, I can't see a way to turn it back on.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar

I've enabled something called the addon bar, but my add-ons are not showing up here (they used to show up in the status bar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great add-on called [Status-4-Evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/?src=ss) that will replace the status bar at the bottom of your screen.  It also takes the place of the add-on bar, so you can put the indicator icons from any other add-ons into the right-hand side of the status bar again.

Incidentally, Status-4-Evar is mentioned at the [bottom of the page you linked](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar#w_how-can-i-get-the-old-status-bar-back).